# change single age into age group by 4 interval

Tags: r

I have a data frame named `df`.

```
df <-tibble (age = c(0,1,2,9,14,23,32,39,44,55,62,74,89,91,96,99, 101))
```

I want to divide the age into ranges as :

```
0-4, 5-9, 10-14, 15-19, 20-24, 25-29, 30-34 ... 95-99, +100
```

Comment: Use `cut` ? `cut(df$age, c(-Inf, 4, 9, 14, .....))`

Comment: thanks but it is not my desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `%/%`.

```
df$age %/% 5
# [1]  0  0  0  1  2  4  6  7  8 11 12 14 17 18 19 19 20
```

To limit the range `pmax` and `pmin` could be used and `paste` for the classes.

```
x <- df$age %/% 5
x <- pmax(0, pmin(20, x))
c(paste(0:19*5, 1:20*5-1, sep="-"), "+100")[x+1]
# [1] "0-4"   "0-4"   "0-4"   "5-9"   "10-14" "20-24" "30-34" "35-39" "40-44"
#[10] "55-59" "60-64" "70-74" "85-89" "90-94" "95-99" "95-99" "+100"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr`:

```
    library(dplyr)
    df <- df %>% 
      mutate(age = ifelse(age %in% c(0:4),"0-4",age),
             age = ifelse(age %in% c(5:9),"5-9",age),
             age = ifelse(age %in% c(10:14),"10-14",age),
             ...,
             age = ifelse(age >= 100, "+100",age))
```

Comment: I'm looking forward a more compact solution